# Android, problem with opening html file in chrome from app

Tags: java, android

I have code for generating html files in my app. I need open last one after saving it to internal storage. I tried code below but app crashed with following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.goodtech.vmaxtr, PID: 19683
             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Vmax/data/Vmax_18_09_18-12_41_12.html
                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:712)
                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:401)
                 at com.goodtech.vmaxtr.data.CsvDB.SaveHTMLFile(CsvDB.java:380)
                 at com.goodtech.vmaxtr.MainActivity$3.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:697)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

The code:

```
try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           byte[] data = htmlDocument.getBytes();
           Uri url = FileProvider.getUriForFile(app.getApplicationContext(), "com.example.fileprovider",file);
           out.write(data);
           out.close();
           Log.e(TAG, "File Save : " + file.getPath());
           shareDocument(url);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

shareDocument

```
  private void shareDocument(Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
```

I need to open this file with chrome, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have file provider paths in the manifest as meta data ?

Comment: show your file provider

Comment: `<provider
           android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true"
           android:exported="false">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
       </provider>`